# Create database script in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two databases DB1 and DB2. Now there are some stored procedure and views in DB1 which are related to DB2 also like this:

```
SELECT ....
FROM DB1.TableA INNER JOIN DB2.TableB 
.....
```

Now, as I have to move these two database to the other server with scripts. I have to make sure that if I am running the script of DB2 I would first run script forthat DB1 object. I am not sure if I can run the script one by one or do I need to prepare one script which will be made based on the dependency?

Any suggestion ?

Comment: you could test this quite easily with a dummy db and tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate scripts for moving data, I would suggest you use the **tasks -> generate scripts** option on the database you want to move. You can choose whether you to script data and schema, or just schema, whether to script indexes, foreign key relationships, and so forth. Quick guide here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/

If I were you though, I would download the trial version of **RedGate SQL Compare**. It has 2 tools called Schema Compare and Data Compare, which allows you to compare 2 databases, and synchronize them schema and data wise. It is a brilliant tool, and we use it everyday to make sure our databases are in sync.

Also, if you have linked servers set up like you say above (DB1 referencing DB2), then it might be worthwhile to take both databases offline, when the traffic on the website is low.
Alternatively, you can create a replica to DB1 and DB2, using SQL Compare/Generate Scripts, and then switch your connection strings to point to the replicas, once they have been ported to the new servers. That way, the switch is instantaneous, and you do not have to take the databases offline.